# Include Excluded rule

Tags: phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I want to include the PSR12 ruleset (which includes the rule "PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName.NotCamelCaps") but I don't want that rule to run on a specific file. so I tried the following ruleset:

```
<rule ref="PSR12">
    <exclude name="PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName.NotCamelCaps"/>
</rule>

<rule ref="PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName.NotCamelCaps">
    <exclude-pattern>packages/test/file</exclude-pattern>
</rule>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't run the "PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName.NotCamelCaps" rule at all (also not in the rest of the code).

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: You've asked PHPCS to exclude the rule from being loaded in that first rule tag. Try removing the exclude from there as you're already excluding it for just the files you want in the second rule tag.

Comment: Thanks That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Greg Sherwood gave the solution: I could just remove the  tag from the PSR12 rule.

```
<rule ref="PSR12">
</rule>

<rule ref="PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName.NotCamelCaps">
    <exclude-pattern>packages/test/file</exclude-pattern>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this....

```
<rule ref="PSR12">
      <exclude name="PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName.NotCamelCaps"/>
</rule>
```

The path of this You find out from
/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/PSR1/Docs/Methods